# Why choose $ab$ and $ab^2$ for group with $6$ elements?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

I'm referring to [this proof](http://www.math.chalmers.se/Math/Grundutb/GU/MMA200/A15/groups6.pdf) (section (c)) which shows that a group with $6$ elements is isomorphic to either $\mathcal{C}_6$ or $\mathcal{S}_3$.

I don't quite get the part why we can pick $ab$ and $ab^2$. I guess we can choose any $c,d$ as elements that have order $2$ (meaning $c^2=e=d^2$), right? So I think the author chose $ab$ and $ba = ab^2$?

Can anyone confirm/explain?

Comment: Since $S_3\cong D_3$, the dihedral group of order six, and $6=2\times 3$, we have that each group of order six is isomorphic to either $\Bbb Z_6$ or $S_3$. This follows from the classification of groups of order $2p$ for prime $p>2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

To see this, if $xy=yx^2$, it suffices to understand that $S_3\cong D_3$ is the [semidirect product $\Bbb Z_3\rtimes \Bbb Z_2$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product), which, when viewed as a presentation, is

$$\langle x,y\mid x^3, y^2, xy=yx^2\rangle.$$

If $xy=yx$, the semidirect product becomes the direct product $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_2$; and then just apply the Chinese remainder theorem.